# Doubt on Nyquist Criterion for MIMO systems

Tags: dynamical-systems, control-theory, linear-control

I am studying MIMO control systems, and I have found that in the Nyquist stability criterion for MIMO system, one of the condition for stability is that:

$det(I+L(j\omega))\neq 0$

and also that

$det(I+L(j\omega))$  has a number of encirclements of the origin equal to the number of poles in the RHP.

but what is $det(I+L(j\omega))$?

In SISO systems I know that we have to look at the encirclements of $L(j\omega)$ around $-1$.

But why in MIMO we have to look at $det(I+L(j\omega))$?

I put here the reference in which I found this: [link](http://people.ee.ethz.ch/~ifa_cs2/Notes_MIMO_Nyquist.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nyquist's stability theorem is actually given in terms of $1+L(j\omega)$, which is the denominator polynomial of the close-loop transfer function.
For SISO system, close-loop stability is examined by looking at the encirclement of $1+L(j\omega)$ around $0$, which is simplified as looking at the encirclement of $L(j\omega)$ around $-1$. Now for MIMO systems, we cannot just use $\det(L(j\omega))$ because that will cause pole-zero cancellation, for example with the plant $\mathrm{diag}\left(\frac{s-1}{s+3},\frac{1}{s-1}\right)$.